# How to save image blob string to use many time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013, winjs

I use FilePicker to load an image and display it with blob like this:

```
var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: false });
// variable file is my picked image.
// It return a string like this: blob:4A851F41-9ADE-4054-9F0E-458E7F134343
```

and when i display it in img tag it work

```
<img src="blob:4A851F41-9ADE-4054-9F0E-458E7F134343" />
// This still work
```

I save that blob string to data.txt and make app auto load data.txt when start the app the blob string not work any more. So can't use this blob string after close the app, as my question how to save image blob string to use many time ?

Comment: no one help again....

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
localSettings.values["blobString"] =  "blob:4A851F41-9ADE-4054-9F0E-458E7F134343"..
```

which will save blob locally.. and you can retrive it anytime.

**Edit:** Take a look at [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) for more info

Comment: thank for your help, can you show me some example code please.

Comment: Wow! would that really save the whole blob locally? I didn't expect that